# convert python 2 to python 3: read image file

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

In python 2, I use:

```
import MySQLdb

pathFileName = "/Users/ldam/Documents/test.png"
f = open(pathFileName, 'r')
img = f.read()
f.close()
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='password', db='db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
inssql = "INSERT Data_images(data) VALUES('%s')"
cursor.execute(inssql % MySQLdb.escape_string(img))
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Arcoding to the comments under, in python 3 I read file as bytes:

```
f = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
img = f.read()
f.close()
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='password', db='db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
inssql = "INSERT Data_images(data) VALUES('%s')"
cursor.execute(inssql % MySQLdb.escape_string(img))
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

However, I have tried many way to insert the img data into table database but none of them work. Can anyone help me to save the img data into database. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you open using `rb` rather than just `r`.

Comment: It's just bytes, so open in `'rb'` mode, and don't decode it at all.

Comment: I've tried it but the result was even more different: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xf3\xffa\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x01\x00\x9a\x9c\x18\x00\x00\nOiCCPPhotoshop ICC profile\x00\x00x\xda\x9dSgTS\xe9\x16=\xf7\xde\xf4BK\x88\x80\x94KoR\x15\x08 RB\x8b\x80\x14\x91&*!\t\x10J\x88!\xa1\xd9\x15Q\xc1\x11EE\x04\x1b\xc8...................'

Comment: The is the right result. You are opening a PNG file. It is not supposed to be printed as text.

Comment: @KlausD. The point is when I used python 2 as descibed above, I have saved the data that way for years, now I want to get the exact result in python 3 so the data can be consistent and be able to be processed the same way. (I only print out to compare the differrences between them)

Comment: The use of the bytes type for binary data is one of the mayor differences of Python 3 compared to version 2. The str type is now for Unicode strings only.

Comment: You just need to keep it as `bytes` object. The text you showed is the REPR of a bytes object, as it should be.

Comment: I will read it as bytes object (read with 'rb' mode) and proccess data saved from python 2 and 3 differently. But first I need to save img data into database. I have tried many ways to save it but unsuccessfully. Can you help me to save img data in python3 into database please?

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all the assertions in the comments that image file should only be be open as byte object, I didn't try to convert it the way I did with finally found the way to save the image data as following:

```
import base64
f = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
img = base64.b64encode(f.read())
f.close()
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='password', db='db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
inssql = "INSERT Data_images(data) VALUES('%s')"
cursor.execute(inssql % MySQLdb.escape_string(img).decode())
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

To convert this data to be process the same way as the data saved in python 2 is quite simple: `base64.b64decode(imgFromDB)`

Comment: So the issue is not "converting python 2 to 3", or reading the data. But rather how it's written to the database. Showing what the actual error is in the original question would help.

Comment: @Keith In the beginning, I was trying to read data and convert it to get exactly the same result as when I did it in python 2. After listen to the advices in the comments,  I understand that it is imposible. So I have to limit what I want to only save into database. After that I have tried to view the data retrieve from database in wxpython and it work after decoded. I didn't mention about wxpython because it take more time to explain and not really what I was focusing on when I asked the question.